# Solr exception java & beginner in solr

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj

i am new in Solr, i wanna use solrj in java, but i get exception for this :

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
```

exception is this :

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

what must i do, and i want to learn solr good, but i couldn't find good any blog, or book and etc. for beginner, if anyone know please write

thanks for all...

Comment: can you post the whole log and the whole code? Are you sure you getting the exception in this line? Did you debug it?

Comment: Please post the full stackstrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception occurs when your Solr instance is not running or when you try to access wrong port. Check port number and restart your Solr instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your SOLR server is not started or it is not listening on port 8983.